# LibGDX - Lwjgl canvas in JFrame not working cross-platform

Tags: java, swing, canvas, libgdx

The problem: I have a GDX desktop application that I want to run inside a JFrame, so that I can spawn other JFrames parented to it, so that when I close the main game the other windows will close as well.

The attempted solution: I run the GDX app in the JFrame application, then get its canvas and add it to the content pane.

Previous code, which works just fine (cross-platform):

```
public class DesktopLauncher {
    public static void main (String[] arg) {
        LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        config.width  = 800;  config.height = 600;
        new LwjglApplication(new GDXRoot(), config);
    }
}
```

New JFrame-based approach (so far, I have only gotten it to work on Windows 8. It doesn't work on OS X, Windows 7, or even Windows 10 technical preview):

```
public class EditModeLauncher extends JFrame {
    final LwjglCanvas canvas;
    LwjglApplicationConfiguration config;

    public EditModeLauncher() {
        config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        config.width  = 800;  config.height = 600;
        config.resizable = false;
        canvas = new LwjglCanvas(new GDXRoot(), config);
        canvas.getCanvas().setSize(800, 600); 
        getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,600));

        final JFrame test = new TestUI(this);
        test.setLocation(800,300);

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Runtime.getRuntime().halt(0); // because of deadlocks with shut down
            }
        });

        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                getContentPane().add(canvas.getCanvas());
                setVisible(true);
                canvas.getCanvas().requestFocus();
            }
        });
        test.setVisible(true);
    }

    private class TestUI extends JFrame {
        private TestUI(final EditModeLauncher parent) {
            // code omitted ...
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] arg) {
        new EditModeLauncher();
    }
}
```

Any ideas what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have windows, but this works for me on Linux Mint:

```
    LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
    config.width = 800;
    config.height = 600;
    ApplicationListener appListener = new MyGdxGame();
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
    new LwjglApplication( appListener, config, canvas );

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    frame.add( canvas );
    frame.setSize( config.width, config.height );
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
    frame.setVisible(true);
```